# How can I increase the hit range of a node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

How can I set the radius or the hit range of a node initialized with texture - an image? Of course I can do that with increasing the size of it, but actually I want to do this without resizing the picture. This node is moving around the screen with a small speed.
Here's my code:

```
monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50.0)
```

How do I detect touches inside the physics body ? I know where it is, i have showPhysics on. Please tell me how to do something when I touch inside this physics body circleOfRadius: anything !

Comment: your physics body determines the hit, just make that bigger

Comment: What do you mean by "result is not changed at all"? Are you saying that physics body is remains unchanged?. If that so, I can't see how to could be possible. Turn visual physics representation and see what's really happening... (skView.showsPhysics = true)

Comment: Well, I mean that after setting the SKPhysicsBody with the circle, the hit range isn't affected. It is still as big as the size of the node ! So the physics body change, but the hit range don't.
Other thing is that after setting this, a strange thing happens - the nodes move at the right direction, but they go up and down too fast without any idea why that happens. 
The showPhysics property helped me visualise the picture, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: it sounds as if there might be something more going on with your scene that you might not be aware of. Another thing to remember is that there's no reason you can't add child nodes to your sprite with their own physics settings (if you wanted to detect the direction of a collision for example).

Comment: I sorted out how to fix the bug with the unexpected moving up and down and rotating. Actually I am quite amused why nobody knows how to do this.
It's only one property for the physics body and that's all.
I will update my question so you guys will know what I still need - hit range ! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a physicsBody and specify the size of the hitbox:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8) )
```

You can also initialize it with a circular shape:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 8.0)
```

Comment: This looks like the correct and straightforward solution, but after I tested it  the result was not changed at all. I'll update my post with the code I use for my nodes.

Comment: Okay , do you know how to detect touches inside this physics body ?